# Mapbox and "Places"

Tags: maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Any idea if MapBox has the concept of "Places" that I can access? I've searched and can't find it, hence this question.

Basically, instead of a city, zip, or building address, I'd like to search for "Liberty Bell", and would like a geo result.

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

I think you searching for this? https://www.mapbox.com/geocoding/

Edit: There exists an example and plugin that should get you going. The plugin provides you with an input field where you can just type in your desired place.

Example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/

Plugin: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder

Comment: That's the geocoding home page :) I'm looking for the "Places"-equivalent implementation: https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: In the geocoding info @Andi-lo points to, it mentions that you can search for things like places and POIs so it does meet the needs of your initial question. If you have other requirements not mentioned in your question please expand and we'll try to help.

Comment: I edited my post with the geocoder example + plugin. But I think you @Vladimir could have found this yourself ;)

Comment: Google places provide much more detailed info. The above MapBox functionality is great if you're looking for building addresses, but if you start typing LA Fitness, it won't retrieve the LA Fitnesses around you. Or if you start typing "Athletic Club", it won't know what you mean, Google does. That's what I was looking for...I guess I wasn't clear enough. But thanks for the reply - that part has already been implemented :)

Comment: I think the real answer here is that MapBox is great for maps and has a limited amount of "Places" data. Google places has a bigger collection of places meta-data.

Comment: As an example, this map would be saturated with additional small businesses, nifty places, etc, if it was displayed using Google Maps: https://www.mapbox.com/analysis-demos/nyc-attractions/#14/40.7236/-74.0050

Comment: You are now comparing two services. Your question wanted to answer the question: "search for "Liberty Bell", and would like a geo result". You can do that with the mapbox geocoding service and my answer should answer your question in that regard. What you are now doing is comparing the google places service to mapbox service which would imply a different question or you need to be more specific on what you ask.